# RenderRepaintBoundary to image without adding Widget to screen

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to export an image from a Widget without adding this Widget to screen.
Is this even possible?
I already succeeded in exporting it by adding to a scrollable container, now I want to render it without adding it to screen and save it to a temp file for sharing.
I think there should be a "paint" call somewhere in there but can't figure out exactly where.

Here's my code:

```
var shareImage = await ShareImageWidget.builder(context,
item: item, definition: definition);
var widget = shareImage.build(context);
var repaint = RepaintBoundary.wrap(widget, 0);
var render = RenderRepaintBoundary(child:repaint.createRenderObject(context));
ui.Image image = await render.toImage(pixelRatio: 1.0);
ByteData byteData = await image.toByteData(format:ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
var pngBytes = byteData.buffer.asUint8List();
var bs64 = base64Encode(pngBytes);
var dir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
```

Comment: https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Offstage-class.html might work for that

Comment: unfortunately when you use that it throws the same error as if you had the widget there with opacity 0.

"
flutter: 'package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart': Failed assertion: line 2882 pos 12: '!debugNeedsPaint': is not true.
"

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer

Comment: did you find a solution to paint a widget without showing it?

Comment: Hey Luca, I didn't. Ended up covering the widget with another one.

Answer (score 8):

Exemple:

```
/// Creates an image from the given widget by first spinning up a element and render tree,
/// then waiting for the given [wait] amount of time and then creating an image via a [RepaintBoundary].
/// 
/// The final image will be of size [imageSize] and the the widget will be layout, ... with the given [logicalSize].
Future<Uint8List> createImageFromWidget(Widget widget, {Duration wait, Size logicalSize, Size imageSize}) async {
  final RenderRepaintBoundary repaintBoundary = RenderRepaintBoundary();

  logicalSize ??= ui.window.physicalSize / ui.window.devicePixelRatio;
  imageSize ??= ui.window.physicalSize;

  assert(logicalSize.aspectRatio == imageSize.aspectRatio);

  final RenderView renderView = RenderView(
    window: null,
    child: RenderPositionedBox(alignment: Alignment.center, child: repaintBoundary),
    configuration: ViewConfiguration(
      size: logicalSize,
      devicePixelRatio: 1.0,
    ),
  );

  final PipelineOwner pipelineOwner = PipelineOwner();
  final BuildOwner buildOwner = BuildOwner();

  pipelineOwner.rootNode = renderView;
  renderView.prepareInitialFrame();

  final RenderObjectToWidgetElement<RenderBox> rootElement = RenderObjectToWidgetAdapter<RenderBox>(
    container: repaintBoundary,
    child: widget,
  ).attachToRenderTree(buildOwner);

  buildOwner.buildScope(rootElement);

  if (wait != null) {
    await Future.delayed(wait);
  }

  buildOwner.buildScope(rootElement);
  buildOwner.finalizeTree();

  pipelineOwner.flushLayout();
  pipelineOwner.flushCompositingBits();
  pipelineOwner.flushPaint();

  final ui.Image image = await repaintBoundary.toImage(pixelRatio: imageSize.width / logicalSize.width);
  final ByteData byteData = await image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);

  return byteData.buffer.asUint8List();
}
```

Reference: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/40064#issuecomment-620081426

There is a package with this feature: https://pub.dev/packages/screenshot#capturing-widgets-that-are-not-in-the-widget-tree

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Transform.translate Widget to move the widget offscreen. [Transform](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Transform-class.html) moves the widget before painting it.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the function from here:

[How to create an image from a widget in Flutter-web?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64132115/11510181)

this feature allows you to translate widgets into images without worrying about hiding those widgets from the screen.
More recently, this has been working on the web as well.