# How to create an image from a widget in Flutter-web?

Tags: google-maps, flutter, google-maps-markers, flutter-web, flutter-image

To display custom widgets on google maps [google_maps_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter) I use a very convenient function that translates any `Widget` (including those containing images) into an `Image`, which I then translate into the `Uint8List` I need. It works great on iOS and Android.

```dart
Future createImageFromWidget( Widget widget){
  final RenderRepaintBoundary repaintBoundary = RenderRepaintBoundary();
  final RenderView renderView = RenderView(
    child: RenderPositionedBox(alignment: Alignment.center, child: repaintBoundary),
    configuration: ViewConfiguration(size: const Size.square(300.0), devicePixelRatio: ui.window.devicePixelRatio),
    window: null,
  );

  final PipelineOwner pipelineOwner = PipelineOwner()..rootNode = renderView;
  renderView.prepareInitialFrame();

  final BuildOwner buildOwner = BuildOwner(focusManager: FocusManager());
  final RenderObjectToWidgetElement<RenderBox> rootElement = RenderObjectToWidgetAdapter<RenderBox>(
    container: repaintBoundary,
    child: Directionality(
      textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
      child: IntrinsicHeight(child: IntrinsicWidth(child: widget)),
    ),
  ).attachToRenderTree(buildOwner);

  buildOwner..buildScope(rootElement)..finalizeTree();
  pipelineOwner..flushLayout()..flushCompositingBits()..flushPaint();

  return repaintBoundary.toImage(pixelRatio: ui.window.devicePixelRatio)
    .then((image) => image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png))
    .then((byteData) => byteData.buffer.asUint8List());
}
```

But unfortunately, when I try to use this function on the Web I get the following error:

> Unsupported operation: toImage is not supported on the Web

Now Flutter has support for `Image.toByteData` and `Picture.toImage` [#20750](https://github.com/flutter/engine/pull/20750), but I can't figure out how this can be used in my case.

Actually the question is - how to remake this function so that it would work on the Web too?

Thank you, I will be glad to any ideas

Comment: The PR shows that its merged to flutter master channel. Could you switch your channel and test it again.?

Comment: @AbhilashChandran I'm using the master branch anyway. Unfortunately, this PR does not imply the implementation of `repaintBoundary.toImage`. Therefore, I am looking for a solution that will do without `repaintBoundary.toImage`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

toImage() works if you put `--dart-define=FLUTTER_WEB_USE_SKIA` on `flutter build web` arguments.

The method works locally without this argument.

I found this solution after seeing the [crop](https://pub.dev/packages/crop) package documentation, which also makes use of toImage()

**EDIT**

I found some problems when accessing the application through the iPhone, the generation of images from a widget works, but some animations that I have in the project stopped working.

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64583461/how-to-use-skia-canvaskit-in-flutter-web) and i will make some tests only using the argument `--dart-define=FLUTTER_WEB_AUTO_DETECT=true` to see if works on desktop, android and iOS correctly with Flutter web.

**EDIT 2**

After some testing on MacOs, the toImage() method works correctly as well.

Comment: It works but the images don't show up. I just see [object ProgressEvent] instead of images. I even added `--web-renderer html`

Answer (score 4):

The `repaintBoundary.toImage` functionality depends on `Scene.toImage` which according to comments in issue [#42767](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/42767#issuecomment-686685779) is not yet implemented for Web.
That issue is also currently deprioritized.

Comment: Thanks for the cue! But in this PR there is no intention to make the `repaintBoundary.toImage` maybe the `Scene.toImage`.