# How to use Skia / CanvasKit in Flutter Web?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web, skia, canvaskit

I know that Flutter supports using Skia instead of DomCanvas in **Flutter Web** using WASM [**CanvasKit**](https://skia.org/user/modules/canvaskit), i.e. "Skia + WebAssembly".

I have heard that this provides significant performance improvements, however, I do not know how to enable it.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can enable **CanvasKit / Skia** in **Flutter Web** by supplying a Dart environment constant:

```dart
flutter run -d chrome --dart-define=FLUTTER_WEB_USE_SKIA=true
```

The `flutter` tools now have a good shortcut for it:

```dart
flutter run -d chrome --web-renderer canvaskit
```

The **`--dart-define=FLUTTER_WEB_USE_SKIA=true`** parameter will set the constant to use Skia. You will also need to supply it to `flutter build web`:

```dart
flutter build web --web-renderer canvaskit
```

[Learn more about **web renderers in Flutter**](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/web-renderers).

### Options

There are [three options](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/web-renderers#choosing-which-option-to-use) for `--web-renderer`:

- `auto (default)` - automatically chooses which renderer to use. This option chooses the HTML renderer when the app is running in a mobile browser, and CanvasKit renderer when the app is running in a desktop browser.
- `html` - always use the HTML renderer.
- `canvaskit` - always use the CanvasKit renderer.

See [*Choosing which option to use*](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/web-renderers#choosing-which-option-to-use) to decide about which option you should be using.

### Alternatives

What I described above can be found in the [`flutter/engine/initialization.dart` file](https://github.com/flutter/engine/blob/cde1e3fca8dcc031b790a1ca535965d1f949f02d/lib/web_ui/lib/src/engine/canvaskit/initialization.dart). Make sure to check the `master` branch to see if the information is still up-to-date.

In there, you can see other options of configuring Flutter Web to use CanvasKit:

#### `FLUTTER_WEB_AUTO_DETECT`

```
--dart-define=FLUTTER_WEB_AUTO_DETECT=true
```

This can now also be done using:

```
--web-renderer auto
```

Supplying this constant will enable auto detect for the renderer detection:

- CanvasKit will be used on desktop devices.
- HTML will be used on mobile devices.

This only holds true if you do not specify `window.flutterWebRenderer`.

`window.flutterWebRenderer`

Iff you enable auto detect (see above), you can specify the renderer in your JavaScript code / HTML file dynamically:

```html
...

<script>
  // This sets the Flutter web renderer in auto detect mode.
  // See https://stackoverflow.com/a/64583462/6509751.
  window.flutterWebRenderer = 'canvaskit';
</script>

<!-- This script installs service_worker.js to provide PWA functionality to
     application. For more information, see:
     https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers -->
<script>
  var serviceWorkerVersion = null;
  ...
```

### Summary

After discovering the [auto detect PR](https://github.com/flutter/engine/pull/21852), I really appreciate the following summary of the current situation in there:

> If auto detect is enabled (set by environment variable `FLUTTER_WEB_AUTO_DETECT`), developers will be allowed to set `window.flutterWebRender` to either canvaskit or html to select the rendering backend.
> If `window.flutterWebRender` is not set, flutter engine will use `canvaskit` for desktop device while using `html` for mobile device.
> If `window.flutterWebRender` is set to an invalid value (not `canvaskit` nor `html`), it will default to `html`.
>
> If auto detect is disabled, it will check the value of environment variable `FLUTTER_WEB_USE_SKIA`. If true, use `canvaksit`. Otherwise, use `html`.

Comment: Is there a way to check whether I am using HTML or canvaskit being used for the rendering part?

Comment: @HappyHaris It is exposed as `useCanvasKit` in the engine (see the linked file in the answer). However, I am not sure how to import the engine library in a Flutter app.

Comment: Was hoping to see an indicator in the inspector of a web browser. Something like the [flt-scene](https://github.com/flutter/engine/blob/cde1e3fca8dcc031b790a1ca535965d1f949f02d/lib/web_ui/lib/src/engine/canvaskit/initialization.dart#L77) tag found in the html.

Answer (score 5):

As described in [Web renderers documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/web-renderers) these are the valid commands to build/run web in **canvaskit** mode:

```
flutter build web --web-renderer canvaskit
```

```
flutter run -d chrome --web-renderer canvaskit
```

> The --web-renderer command line option takes one of three values, auto, html, or canvaskit.
>
> - `auto` (default) - automatically chooses which renderer to use. This option chooses the HTML renderer when the app is running in a mobile browser, and CanvasKit renderer when the app is running in a desktop browser.
> - `html` - always use the HTML renderer.
> - `canvaskit` - always use the CanvasKit renderer.

Answer (score 0):

## To run locally

### with  skia

`flutter run -d Chrome --dart-define=FLUTTER_WEB_USE_SKIA=true --release`

### with canvas kit

`flutter run -d Chrome --dart-define=FLUTTER_WEB_CANVASKIT_URL=true --release`

`flutter run -d Chrome --dart-define=FLUTTER_WEB_CANVASKIT_FORCE_CPU_ONLY=true --release`

Answer (score 0):

You can also **enforce it at runtime** adding this to your `web/index.html`:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function (ev) {
        // Download main.dart.js
        _flutter.loader.loadEntrypoint({
          serviceWorker: {
            serviceWorkerVersion: serviceWorkerVersion,
          },
          onEntrypointLoaded: async function(engineInitializer) {

        // Configure the engine options
        let engineOptions = new _flutter.JsFlutterConfiguration();
        engineOptions.renderer = "canvaskit";

        // Initialize the Flutter engine
        let appRunner = await engineInitializer.initializeEngine(engineOptions);

        // Run the app
        await appRunner.runApp();
      }
    });
  });
```

Here is the documentation for [web renderers](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/web/renderers) and [customizing web app initialization](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/web/initialization).