# Assigning CanvasKit / Skia in Flutter Web causes my Googlemap's plugin to request 2 fingered use on mobile

Tags: flutter, google-maps, canvaskit

I have mad jank when scrolling a ListView. Its scrolling a column of Text widgets interspersed with ElevatedButton Widgets, each time the user Scrolls and an ElevatedButton scrolls into view there's a bunch of jank, horrible.

On Flutter web desktop this doesn't happen, so I forced Flutter web mobile to use Skia rendering, by inserting this into my index.html file:

```
<script>
  // This sets the Flutter web renderer in auto detect mode.
  // See https://stackoverflow.com/a/64583462/6509751.
  window.flutterWebRenderer = 'canvaskit';
</script>
```

But this seemingly causes the Googlemap's plugin to believe that it is being used on a desktop not mobile, and it requests 2 fingered use.

This is not the paradigm for Googlemaps on mobile and I vaguely believe jank is better.

I would like it to work well on both desktop & mobile, is there a way to correct the google map plugin to use the mobile / desktop paradigms?